# Elevate to Privilege Level

Tags: automation, ansible, cisco-ios

When I am running this on Ansible on GNS3, I am getting this error. Can anyone please help me with this error?

Hosts File

```
[ios]
172.20.10.55

[ios:vars]
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_user=admin
ansible_password=cisco
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=enable
```

Playbook

```
- name: multiple commands
  hosts: ios
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: configure ospf
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - configure terminal
          - 10 pemrit ip host 192.168.1.1 any log
        parents: ip access-list extended test
```

Error

```
TASK [configure ospf] **********************************************************
fatal: [172.20.10.55]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [\nR1>] with error: failed to elevate privilege to enable mode still at prompt [\nR1>]"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.20.10.55               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Try adding that `ansible_become: yes` and `ansible_become_method: enable` and `ansible_become_password: "{{ansible_become_password}}"` to the `ios_config` module options.

Comment: Oh, wait.  Try setting `ansible_become_password` in your vars.

Comment: @Jack There is no such variable ansible_become_password in network_cli

Comment: The docs say there is: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html

Comment: Strange. Here they mention it but in network_cli documentation there isn't any.
I will try it and let you know. Thanks.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/network_cli.html

Comment: @Jack Thanks!! It solved the issue :))

Comment: I'll make it an answer, then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `ansible_become_password`.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html